# Magento 2 - Which function / controller has triggered my plugin?

Tags: magento2, plugin, save

I have setup a plugin which runs after a customer is saved. This means that the plugin runs on the following situations

**Frontend**

- When a customer register
- When a customer updates their name

**Backend**

- When an admin registers a customer
- When an admin updates a customer

What I would like to know is, how can I see which one of the 4 options has triggered the plugin to run?

The reason for this is that I would like to have slightly different logic in the plugin if the admin saves a customer

Answer (score 0):

You could always check which area the plugin is run in by asking the app state:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\State as AppState;

class CustomerPlugin
{
    protected $appState;

    public function __construct(
        AppState $appState
    ) {
        $this->appState = $appState;
    }

    public function afterSave(CustomerInterface $customer, $result)
    {
        try {
            $area = $this->appState->getArea();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // area has not been set, either exit or assume some other state or area
        }

        switch ($area) {
            case "adminhtml":
                // do admin stuff
                break;
            case "frontend":
                // do frontend stuff
                break;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example - I have tweaked it so that it works as it needs to call $this->appState->getAreaCode(); and not getAreaCode().

Though the only issue is that I was hoping I would be able to see which 1 of the 4 has triggered the plugin. Is there a way to do this?